# How does the C# compiler distinguish between a concrete subclass impl of an abstract method and an overload in the abstract base?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, compiler-construction, overloading

If you have a base class

```
public abstract class AbsHashtableish<TKey, TValue>
{
    public abstract TKey ConvertToKey(string key);
    public abstract bool KeyExists(TKey key);

    public virtual bool KeyExists(string key)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("In Base");
         return KeyExists(ConvertToKey(key));
    }
}
```

and a concerete class

```
public class ConcreteHashtableish: AbsHashtableish<string, Dinosaur>
{
    ...

    public override string ConvertToKey(string key)
    {
         return key;
    }

    public override bool KeyExists(string key)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("In Sub");
         return _list.Contains(key);
    }
}
```

and client A

```
AbsHashtableish<string, Dinosaur> concreteA = new ConcreteHashtableish<string, Dinosaur>();
```

and client B

```
ConcreteHashtableish<string, Dinosaur> concreteB = new ConcreteHashtableish<string, Dinosaur>();
```

What are the rules (and if possible, the reasoning behind them) for determining whether the code shown above is sufficient to compile and if so:

1. Is there a difference between calling `KeyExists` on `concreteA` vs `concreteB`?
2. Assuming we can somehow enter the base class method `KeyExists(string key)`, will we be able to get out of it?

For question #2, what I mean is that if somehow the compiler is able to compile this code, does it do so by effectively hiding the base method from the client - because if that code was reached, it would result in an infinite loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `KeyExists` on both `convreteA` and `concreteB` is eventually the same.

The `Common Language Runtime (CLR)` knows to invoke methods on the actual type (using a [Virtual Method Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)). This is the whole point of [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). It allows you to refer concrete implementations as abstract ones, but the actual methods getting called are of the concrete types.

In the particular example you gave, you can't use the base class implementation of `KeyExists` from outside the derived class, simply because you can't create an instance of an abstract class. If it wasn't abstract, you can create:

```
AbsHashtableish<string, Dinosaur> baseA = new AbsHashtableish<string, Dinosaur>();
```

And `AbsHashtableish.KeyExists` will get called.

EDIT: (Thanks to Oliver for noting)

You can always call the base class implementation from inside a derived class. In this case you would call:

```
base.KeyExists(key)
```

Comment: within the concrete class you can call the base implementation by using `base.KeyExists(key)`.

Comment: @AndroidJoker so is it fair to say that the compiler writes instructions to the CLR that say "Call this or that particular implementation of KeyExists" or instead instructions that say "Call KeyExists, I know you can figure it out when the time comes."

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos: Down in the IL code only stands "Call KeyExists" and the runtime will then look into the vtable of that class. There is a pointer to the method that should be called and if the derived classes overwrote it, it points to the concrete implementation, otherwise to the base implementation. Creation of the vtable stuff happens when the runtime loads the type. But I'm not a specialist, so anyone can correct me if I mixed something up.